# Print machine type from Google Cloud Monitoring API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, monitoring, stackdriver

I'm retrieving metrics from my Google Cloud Compute Engine instances with Node.js using this [library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-monitoring/blob/master/samples/metrics.js).

I can create a time series with following result:

```
{
    "points": [...],
    "metric": {
        "labels": {
            "instance_name": "instance-1"
        },
        "type": "compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/usage_time"
    },
    "resource": {
        "labels": {
            "instance_id": "3123123123123412",
            "zone": "europe-west1-d",
            "project_id": "..."
        },
        "type": "gce_instance"
    },
    "metricKind": "DELTA",
    "valueType": "DOUBLE",
    "metadata": null
},
```

The problem is that it doesn't print the machine type (e.g. n1-standard-1) and/or number vCPUs, etc. Is it possible to change the request to all print machine type information?

Answer (score 0):

Stackdriver metric responses will depend on the available **fields** on any given monitored **resource**. In this case, your request is getting all the information available to the [`gce_instance` **resource**](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_gce_instance): `project_id`, `instance_id`, and `zone`.

The `compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/*` **metric type** is taken at the hypervisor level, not inside the instance, so it lacks more details. If you want to get information about the instance itself, you could install the Stackdriver Monitoring Agent on your instances, and change your **metric type** to the [agent cpu metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-cpu): `agent.googleapis.com/cpu/*`

In this case, changing the **metric type** and maintaining `usage_time` would return `cpu_number` and `cpu_state` in addition to the other labels. I believe it would look something like this:

```
{
    "points": [...],
    "metric": {
        "labels": {
            "instance_name": "[INSTANCE_NAME]"
        },
        "type": "agent.googleapis.com/cpu/usage_time"
    },
    "resource": {
        "labels": {
            "instance_id": "[INSTANCE_ID]",
            "zone": "[ZONE]",
            "project_id": "[PROJECT_ID]",
            "cpu_number": "[CPU_NUMBER]",
            "cpu_state": "[CPU_STATE]"
        },
        "type": "gce_instance"
    },
    "metricKind": "CUMULATIVE",
    "valueType": "INT64",
    "metadata": null
},
```

Installing the agent would give you access to [several other](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent) metric types, resources, and their resource labels. While I don't believe machine type is directly available, you should be able to get the rest of the information.